# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.casper.evaluate(function _evaluate()

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am writing a simple test. Essentially, I need the ability to go to 2 urls and assert that a particular text exists.

I have below sample code for that. When I execute the code, I get an error "FAIL TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.casper.evaluate(function _evaluate()". The 4th assert - test.assertTextExists is the one that fails. Can someone please help me investigate this issue...

CasperJs version: casperjs-1.1.3
PhantomJs version: phantomjs-2.1.1-windows

```
var baseurl = "http://www.t-mobile.com";

casper.test.begin('T-Mobile page contains Unlimited Talk & Text - 2', 2, function suite(test) {
    casper.start(baseurl + "/businessoffer/unlimited-data-story.html", function() {
        test.assertTitle("Unlimited Data For Business | Data Rollover and Free Streaming");
        test.assertTextExists('It’s YOUR data, use it however YOU want.');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});

casper.test.begin('T-Mobile page contains Unlimited Talk & Text', 2, function suite(test) {
    casper.start(baseurl + "/businessoffer/wifi-calling-wifi-extenders.html", function() {
        test.assertTitle("Wifi Calling & Wifi Extenders for Better Service at Home | T-Mobile");
        test.assertTextExists('Unlimited talk & text');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Which CasperJS and PhantomJS version do you use?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying @Artjom. I added the CasperJs, PhantomJs version in my post.